# Freenode IRC webchat cannot log in

Tags: kiwi-irc

When I tried to log in https://webchat.freenode.net/, this error shows:

```
Closing link: (~web-4@xx.x.xx.xxx) [You must use TLS/SSL and authenticate via SASL to connect to freenode please visit https://irc.com/login/sso in order to create an account. SASL Configuration: https://freenode.net/kb/answer/sasl - Webchat: https://webchat.freenode.net/]
```

Comment: https://webchat.freenode.net/ cannot use too.

Comment: So the registration to irc.com

Comment: And anyone who wants to find someplace to chat about the FOSS project, web.libera.chat will be a nice location! I just found it one day ago.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here, It doesn't connect at all. And I am a registered user.

[image]

Comment: Seems Freenode is going away, nobody can explain it. They just downcast this question and any active answers, so sad!

Comment: I'll suggest using web.libera.chat instead where I have been these days.